# Why does @SolrDocument doesn't create collection/core if it doesn't exist and throw 404 error

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, spring-data-solr, solrclient

Is there a way to create automatically in solr server startup or programmatically in spring-data-jpa using any annotations?